# How to create ShareFileClient without specifying it's size to be able to stream data to it?

Tags: c#, .net, azure, fileshare

I would like to create new blob on FileShareClient in Azure FileShare resource with .NET api. I cannot specify it's size in the beginning (because it will be filled with data later eg. csv file filled with lines, up to couple of GBs).

I was trying to use something like this in my code:

```
using Azure.Storage.Files.Shares

  ShareFileClient fileShare = new ShareFileClient(
            "MYConnectionString",
            "FileShareName",
            "TestDirectoryName");
  if (!fileShare.Exists())
        {
            fileShare.Create(0);
        }
var stream = fileShare.OpenWrite(true, 0);
```

[Edit]
I have got an exception: System.ArgumentException: 'options.MaxSize must be set if overwrite is set to true' Is there any way to avoid specyfining this size?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Micro$ofts infinite wisdom: resize is hidden in SetHttpHeaders method.

```
public void AppendFile(string filePath, byte[] data)
{
    ShareFileClient fileShare = new ShareFileClient(connectionString, shareClient.Name, filePath);
    if (!fileShare.Exists())
        fileShare.Create(0);

    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        var properties = fileShare.GetProperties();
        var openOptions = new ShareFileOpenWriteOptions();

        fileShare.SetHttpHeaders(properties.Value.ContentLength + data.Length);

        var stream = fileShare.OpenWrite(false, properties.Value.ContentLength, openOptions);

        stream.Write(data, 0, data.Length);

        stream.Flush();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Please try to use the latest package [Azure.Storage.Files.Shares, version 12.5.0](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Azure.Storage.Files.Shares/).

Note, in the code `new ShareFileClient()`, the last parameter is the `directory name + file name`.

see the code below:

```
        ShareFileClient f2 = new ShareFileClient(connectionString, shareName, dirName + "/test.txt");
        if (!f2.Exists())
        {
            f2.Create(0);
        }
```

The file with 0 size can be created, here is the test result:

[image]

Comment: I have tried your solution but when i try to open write in this way:
                    var stream = f2.OpenWrite(true, 0);
I have got an exception:
System.ArgumentException: 'options.MaxSize must be set if overwrite is set to true'

Is there any way to avoid specyfining this size?

Comment: @JacknJ, the answer is no if you set `true` for `OpenWrite` method. And if you want to overwrite the file, it's easy to set the MaxSize(and it should be larger the data you want to upload). For example: `ShareFileOpenWriteOptions options = new ShareFileOpenWriteOptions{ MaxSize = 30}; var openwrite_stream = f2.OpenWrite(true, 0,options:options);`

Comment: @JacknJ, Hello, if the answer is helpful, could you please accept it as answer:). Thanks.  And if you still have more issues, please @ me.